# I am having this Error: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

Im having problems with my Game, i seem to be having this error coming out when i try to move to the next keyframe: at InventoryDemo/collision()[InventoryDemo::frame2:123]

I did a debug and it shows me that the error is somewhere here:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision)
function collision(event:Event):void{
 if(girl.hitTestObject(dust))
 {
    mushroom.visible = true;
    mclick.visible = true;
 }
```

I dont know why the error is coming out

Comment: The button which i assigned the the frame where the code is in, skips the frame i want it to go to.

Comment: what is exactly the line 123 ?

Comment: he's referencing an object that doesn't exist in the keyframe,that's that simple.

Comment: @BotMaster the object is girl, and everything runs fine except when i click on my button that takes me to the next frame, thats when the error occurs..

Comment: @akmozo my debugging points out to line 123 in which indicates the code: if(girl.hitTestObject(dust))

Comment: You are referencing 4 objects, girl, dust, mushroom, mclick. One of them or more doesn't exist and is null.

Comment: Verify that `girl` is accessible on the **frame 2**.

Comment: girl is indeed in the frame, the error only appears when i click on the button to go to the next frame...

Comment: According to the error message and to you, the only object in the line 123 that have a method is `girl`, and of course the error will appear only when you press the button to go to the next frame which will fire the `onEnterFrame` event and then that error.

Comment: If you are sure that your `girl` object exists then you must ensure that's a `DisplayObject`. Try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : ( not tested )

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision)
function collision(event:Event):void{

    if(MovieClip(girl).hitTestObject(dust)) {
        mushroom.visible = true
        mclick.visible = true
    }

}
```

EDIT

Some tests to verify existance of `girl` object :

```
trace(girl is DisplayObject) // gives : true

trace(girl is MovieClip)    // gives : true

trace(girl.hitTestObject)   // gives : function Function() {}
```

Comment: @Hank, If you are sure that your `girl` object exists then you must ensure that's a `DisplayObject`.

Comment: What do you mean, like i have to declare it? sorry im really new to as

Comment: yes i got all the results, i placed the trace inside the if statement.... and this is what i got: true
true
function Function() {}

Comment: could you give me the exact error with details because it's a little weird, or we really missed something ;)

Comment: this is what im getting when i click on the button to move to the next frame: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at InventoryDemo/collision()[InventoryDemo::frame2:124] frame2:124 - is pointing at " if(MovieClip(girl).hitTestObject(dust))"

Comment: sight...there dont seem to be any problems but the error keeps showing up

Comment: You told me that you have placed the traces inside the if statement but which `if` ?

Comment: So the problem is not in that line !! disable these lines, one each time, and tell me : `mushroom.visible = true` and `mclick.visible = true`

Comment: its still the same...what does it mean...Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference?

Comment: This is really very strange !! Could you send me your source code (gdrive, mega, ...) in any way you choose ?

Comment: addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision)
 function collision(event:Event):void
 {
  if(MovieClip(girl).hitTestObject(dust))
  {
   
  mushroom.visible = true;
  mclick.visible = true;
  
  }
  else
  {
   
  }
 }

Comment: the next function is this...skip_now.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);

function click2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 
 gotoAndStop("start1");
 
  
}